# GPIO Switch Issue

Tags: python

I am writing a PICO application that sends a urequest.

So far, I have everything done to what I feel is right until I execute python.

In my code, I have a while True statement starting my loop, so its listening for the change from 1 to 0. My question is, does this have to constantly send that 0 or 1? When I print pin.value, python is constantly returning a value.

I left my PICO running all night, and not to my surprise; the PICO was unresponsive this morning. I assume I ram out of ram. Is there a better way of handling a switch?

```
from machine import Pin
import urequests
import network
import secrets
import time

wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)
wlan.connect(secrets.SSID, secrets.PASSWORD)

led = Pin(17, Pin.OUT)
pinA = Pin(16, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)

#STR data for URL DECODE
switchon = str(1)
switchoff = str(0)

#PICO NAME for Database
station_name = 'PicoWifi'


def get_pinA():
    return not pinA.value()
    
def pinA_ON():
    led.value(1)
    r = urequests.get(url=PHP_DECODE_URL_HIDDEN).text
    
def pinB_OFF():
    led.value(0)
    r = urequests.get(url=PHP_DECODE_URL_HIDDEN).text

while True:
    if get_pinA() == 1:
        pinA_ON()
        
    else:
        pinB_OFF()
```

Comment: I did add a break at the of "if" and "else" at the end, and the switch became not responsive. I also tried remove the while statement just have the if/else statement and nothing as well.

Comment: After some more research edge detection might be what I need?

Comment: If you want to do something once when you press a button and again when you press it again after releasing it, then edge detection is what you need. You might also need debouncing.

Comment: This seems to be a general programming question.

Comment: *"does this have to constantly send that 0 or 1"* -> You are thinking about this the wrong way.  By analogy, you could (correctly) consider a light bulb to be constantly sending out light, as long as it is on -- and the light is **always** either "constantly" on, or "constantly" off.  There are no other states.  If you then "constantly" stare at the light, until someone turns it off, it will indeed continue to constantly send out light.  Similarly, the state of a GPIO input is always one thing or another, constantly.  It does not cease to exist after you check the state.

Comment: `does this have to constantly send that 0 or 1?` ... that is your choice ... you can constantly print the value ... or you can remember what the value is at each cycle, and then print only if the value changes